# Type annotations for a variable whose type changes over time

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have stored stringified object to local storage in a typescript project.

When am trying to get the localStorage data ,it is not working with type annotation "string"

```
let str : string = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");

let UserData = JSON.parse(str);
```

The above code gives me the following error on line 1 :
error: Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)

It is working with type annotation "any".

```
let str: any = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");

let UserData = JSON.parse(str);
```

But as per the requirement am not supposed to use "any".

Edit :: 
This doesn't work, even for

```
let UserData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userDetails")||"{}");
```

So raised as a new question.

Comment: Check if it's a string `if (typeof str === 'string')` or `str !== null` whichever you like more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage.getItem('userDetails')` can return either string or null. Returns string when the `userDetails`' object exists in localStorage (`string`) and `null` if it doesn't. So the type you get from the method is `string | null`.

Now you need to make TypeScript sure the type of str is string. TS is smart and will detect if you checked for the type eg. in an if before

```
// TS will set the type of str automatically to string | null,
// because that's the return type of localStorage.getItem()
let str = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");

if(typeof str === 'string') {
  let UserData = JSON.parse(str);
  //rest of your UserData related logic here
}
```

You could also do

`let str : string = localStorage.getItem("userDetails") || '{}'`, then if localStorage returns null `str` will resolve to an stringified object, and then you can handle the error behavior in the value of `let userData`.

Comment: The above solution works  , with a slight change.
    let str : string = localStorage.getItem("userDetails") || '"
Thanks @Artur Tagisow

Comment: Using `let str =  getItem("userDetails") || ""` AND `if(typeof stry === 'string')` is redundant. Because if you use the || operator (if userDetails is null, set str to ""), `str` will always be of type `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Your error means that fetched data can be null;

The simplest solution:

```
let str : string | null = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
```

Alternatives:

```
let str : string = localStorage.getItem("userDetails") && localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
```

Or:

```
const item = localStorage.getItem("userDetails");
let str : string = '';
  if (item) {
  str = item;
}
```

Comment: Your "alternative" with `&&` is a race condition prone.